# scrollview horizontal

Tags: android, xml

Всем Добра! Ребята, нужна Ваша помощь!

**Имеется следующая разметка:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/way"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/time"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>  
    </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/more"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Как правильно это обернуть в `scrollview horizontal`? Дело в том, что когда я пытался, получалось не очень. У меня кнопки равноудалены от друг от друга, и когда я пытался обернуть их, то они прилипают к друг другу. Нужна Ваша помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно будут сжиматься, т.к. у родителя `match_parent`, а расстояние за счет весов. Измените на `wrap_content`, задайте нужные отступы и поместите в `ScrollView`. К примеру:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/FAB5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]